# flutter GenerateMocks is not generated mock class

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mocking, flutter-getx, widget-test-flutter

I am trying to use `@GenerateMocks` on my test method, This is my dev dependancies:

```
dev_dependencies:
  test: any
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.4
  build_runner: ^2.1.4
  mockito: ^5.0.0
  mocktail: ^0.2.0
```

and I am using like this:

```
@GenerateMocks([CustomerPOAutocompleteState])
void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

But after running `flutter pub run build_runner build` nothing is generated?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is it but i've just put the `import 'my_test_file.mocks.dart';` after the `@GenerateMocks` annotation and worked fine.

before:

```
@GenerateMocks([MyClass])
```

after:

```
@GenerateMocks([MyClass])
import 'my_test_file.mocks.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation

> If you need to mock your GetxController/GetxService, you should extend GetxController, and mixin it with Mock, that way

```dart
class NotificationServiceMock extends GetxService 
       with Mock implements NotificationService {}
```

I directly added `mockito` on `dependencies`.

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  dartz: ^0.10.1
  mockito: ^5.2.0 #here


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.1.11
```

Make sure to create some methods on your abstract class, in my case it is `RestaurantRepository` and will be annotated like `@GenerateMocks([RestaurantRepository])`.

And then run

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

On  test file

```dart
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

@GenerateMocks([RestaurantRepository])
void main() {
  late MockRestaurantRepository mockRestaurantRepository;
//...}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It did not work, Not able to create mock class

Comment: can you provide sample `CustomerPOAutocompleteState`?

Comment: sure https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jPtm3rpqtn/

Comment: Can you try like `class CustomerPOAutocompleteState extends GetxController with Mock implements ICustomerPoAutocompleteService`

Comment: At test class ?

Comment: if I right I tested this `class MockController extends GetxController with Mock implements ICustomerPoAutocompleteService{}

@GenerateMocks([MockController])
void main() {`

Comment: I added to main class but It not works too